# How to make a vertical timeline with HTML, CSS, and Flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox, timeline

I am making a vertical timeline with HTML and CSS. My idea is to use a CSS border for each step. I am using "border-right" for one step and "border-left" for the next step. In theory, wouldn't this make the line perfectly in the middle? But, the line is *not* in the middle. The line looks broken. This is where I need help. Can you please look at my CSS/HTML and help center the middle line perfectly? I would like to make this a template, so I can copy and paste each step forever, if needed.

I need help getting the center black line to align to center for all of the steps. What am I doing wrong?

```css
.step {
  display: flex;
}

.img-left,
.img-right {
  padding: 30px;
}

.info-right,
.info-left {
  padding: 30px;
}

.info-right {
  border-left: 1px black solid;
}

.info-left {
  border-right: 1px black solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="timeline-holder">
  <h1>Timeline</h1>
  <div class="step">
    <div class="img-left">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="info-right">
      <h2>Placeholder Title</h2>
      <p>Placeholder text. Placeholder text. Placeholder text. Placeholder text. Placeholder text.</p>
      <ul>
        <li>Placeholder text</li>
        <li>Placeholder text</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="step">
    <div class="info-left">
      <h2>Placeholder Title</h2>
      <p>Placeholder text. Placeholder text. Placeholder text. Placeholder text. Placeholder text.</p>
      <ul>
        <li>Placeholder text</li>
        <li>Placeholder text</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- end .info-left -->
    <div class="img-right">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

View on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/matie/pen/JxGOZX).

Comment: You need to set the widths of the items on the left to be the same if you want them to line up...

Comment: Ah, crap. Yes. I just need to add "flex: 1;" to .info-right,.info-left, .img-left, and .img-right

Comment: For this example you could use a table aswell

Comment: Here is the answer to your question that got taken down: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GzjBqK

Comment: @RickSibley Thanks! That's my CodePen post. Lol.

Comment: Yeah, I just fixed the part that you were asking for. Pretty much added the loop that looks if the active class is applied, if it is not then it will apply the class to the selected anchor.

Comment: Oh, shoot! Looks great. I knew there was a better way! Hey, quick question. @RickSibley do you happen to know how to make the side links "active" when users scroll through the section as well? I realize, with my approach, it takes the user clicking on the link to make it active. It'd be awesome to figure out a way to code it, so that when user scrolls past the section it lights up as well. No biggy, let me know. Best, - Matie

Comment: Try this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GzjBqK (Same link just updated the code.) *Note: there are changes to the HTML so be sure if you are trying to reproduce you look at all the changes*

Comment: Nice! That is exactly what I was trying to do. Many thanks.

Comment: P.S. you are very kind and thoughtful for sharing this response here! The other board tore me apart. I would have voted your answer as the correct answer. Thank you for helping again!! @RickSibley

Comment: Anytime! Yeah, it's crazy on here. There are nice people though. Wishing you the best on your project :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A flex item will grow or shrink to fit the space available in its flex container. You have to take control over that behaviour with the **[flex CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex)**.
 Also give your images a `max-width`.

```css
.step {
    display: flex;
}

.step img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.step h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.step__left, .step__right {
    padding:30px;
    flex: 0 0 200px;
}

.step__right {
    border-left:1px black solid;
    background-color: rgba(0,255,0,0.1);
}

.step__left {
    border-right:1px black solid;
    background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="timeline-holder">
    <h1>Timeline</h1>
        <div class="step">
            <div class="step__left">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"/>
            </div>
            <div class="step__right">
                <h2>Placeholder Title</h2>
                <p>Placeholder text. Placeholder text. Placeholder text. Placeholder text. Placeholder text.</p>
                <ul>
                    <li>Placeholder text</li>
                    <li>Placeholder text</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="step">
            <div class="step__left">
                <h2>Placeholder Title</h2>
                <p>Placeholder text. Placeholder text. Placeholder text. Placeholder text. Placeholder text.</p>
                <ul>
                    <li>Placeholder text</li>
                    <li>Placeholder text</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="step__right">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"/>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I think this is formatted more clean, than my original... What does, "flex: 0 0 200px;" mean?

Comment: Click on "flex CSS property", I provided a link. First number sets grow, second one shrink, third one the basis calculated on. Set the first number to one, so that both columns grow to fit the parent container. Yes, you can make it responsive. I would stack the blocks on small viewports. Use your flex with a media query, to let it kick in in a higher viewport for columns.

Comment: Depending on the content, you could have two columns even for smaller viewports.

Comment: Ah! I see. Stacking on small viewports is smart. I will do that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
.img-left, .img-right {
    padding:30px;
    flex:1;
}
.info-right,.info-left {
    padding:30px;
    flex:1;
}
```

+Add "flex:1;" to make them equal widths.

Comment: Although, when I shrink this down to a phone size, the lines are not aligned... :-(